# For (key of me_labba){} notworking

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have used this code same theory I have used but 1one work but 2nd does not work in JavaScript

```js
var me_labba = {
  name: 'kezara',
  bd: '1999'
};
var str_walata_awlak_na = "sdasdasd"
let key;

//1st one
for (key of str_walata_awlak_na) {
  console.log(key);
}
//2nd one
for (key of me_labba) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `for...of` on plain objects. It only works on iterables like arrays or strings.

Comment: *"1one work but 2nd does not work"*: Use `for..in` for the second loop instead. In the first one you don't iterate *keys* -- the variable name is misleading -- those are *values* (characters) of the (iterable) string.

Answer (score 1):

Use for in with Objects in in Javascript

```
for (key in me_labba){
    console.log(key);
}
```

Or use Object.keys

```
Object.keys(me_labba).forEach((k) => console.log(k))
```